# Radio buttons that sort database in price order suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a site that displays data on travel products from a MySQL database. There are radio buttons above for the user to choose if they want to display the results in ascending price order or descending price order.

This was working fine with until I tried to make it look neater on the page by putting it in a table. I also had to change the 'name' tags so that they were both the same so that the user couldn't select both the ascending and descending options and mess up the query. I think one of these contributed to messing it up.

It used to sort the items by price perfectly when the user clicked the appropriate radio button and then the search button next to it. But now it doesn't do anything. Much appreciated if someone could help. Probably a simple error.

HTML:

```
<form action="ayia-napa-holidays.php" method="get">
            <table width="280" height="25" >

                <tr><td width="61"><p>Sort by:</p></td>
                <td width="72" height="24"><p>Lowest price</p></td>
                <td width="28"><input name="priceorder" type="radio" value="priceorderasc" /></td>

                <td width="75" height="24"><p>Highest price</p></td>
                <td width="20"><input name="priceorder" type="radio" value="priceorderdesc" /></td>

            </tr></table>
            <input name="searchform1" type="submit" value="Search" class="moreinfobutton" />
            </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 

            //connect
                include ("db.connect.php");

                $pages_query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM `holidaytable` WHERE brandname = 'Cyprus'");
                $count = mysql_result($pages_query, 0);


                echo '<p>There are '.$count.' holidays<hr></p>';                    
                //construct query and insert values

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM holidaytable WHERE brandname = 'Cyprus'";


                if (isset($_GET['priceorderasc'])) $sql .= " ORDER BY buynow ASC";
                if (isset($_GET['priceorderdesc'])) $sql .= " ORDER BY buynow DESC";


                $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

            include("dbresults.php");

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get name is `$_GET['priceorder']` (saying your using the `GET` method on the `<from>` for the Radios. So, you will need something like this, using your current code:

```
if(isset($_GET['priceorder']) && !empty($_GET['priceorder']))
{
  if ($_GET['priceorder'] == 'priceorderasc') $sql .= " ORDER BY buynow ASC";
  if ($_GET['priceorder'] == 'priceorderdesc') $sql .= " ORDER BY buynow DESC";
}
```

No need to check if it is set twice, empty check is just a backup and optional.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a simple error.

Apparently, before you changed the element names, they were named `priceorderasc` and `priceorderdesc`. Now you changed that name to `priceorder`, but not the variables PHP checks against when building the query. What you need to change is:

```
if ($_GET['priceorder'] == 'priceorderasc') $sql .= " ORDER BY buynow ASC";
if ($_GET['priceorder'] == 'priceorderdesc') $sql .= " ORDER BY buynow DESC";
```

So that PHP checks the value of the new element name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it though and I ended up with an undefined index error on those lines. I tried the other answer below and it worked. +1 for your response though. :)